# Eliminar datos duplicado en columnas sql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

tengo los siguientes datos que recolecto de una tabla temporal como ven son los días en la cual realizan sus labores el problema se da básicamente desde el día lunes al domingo cuando realizan mas de 2 labores ya sea por hora o por avance y el resultado es lo visto en la imagen con el código 2256 y aquí es donde tengo la necesidad de poder eliminar estos duplicados porque posteriormente se hace una agrupación para un listado de persona que asistieron a laborar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí coloco el código que me trae los datos a la tabla temporal, el problema estaría en la vista que hago previo a seleccionar los datos

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#CUADROCOMP') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #CUADROCOMP;
END 

SET LANGUAGE SPANISH; 
CREATE TABLE #CUADROCOMP (
EMPLCOD INT,
SUPERVISOR VARCHAR(50),
AREA VARCHAR(50),
LUNES VARCHAR(50),
MARTES VARCHAR(50),
MIERCOLES VARCHAR(50),
JUEVES VARCHAR(50),
VIERNES VARCHAR(50),
SABADO VARCHAR(50),
DOMINGO VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO #CUADROCOMP(AREA,SUPERVISOR,LUNES,MARTES,MIERCOLES,JUEVES,VIERNES,SABADO,DOMINGO,EMPLCOD)
         SELECT 
          (SELECT ISNULL(CASE WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='EMPAQUE MANUAL PAGO POR DIA') THEN 'EMPAQUE            '
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='EMPAQUE NORMAL') THEN 'EMPAQUE'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='EMPAQUE MANUAL 2') THEN 'EMPAQUE'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='EMPAQUE MANUAL') THEN 'EMPAQUE'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='COCINA PAGO POR DIA') THEN 'COCINA'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='COCINA POR HORA') THEN 'COCINA'
                             WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='CAMARA PAGO POR DIA') THEN 'CAMARA' END,
         (SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)))AS AREA,       
        (SELECT DISTINCT(S.NOM_SUPERVISOR) FROM
  TBL_SECCION D
  INNER JOIN
  TBL_SUPERVISOR S
  ON S.COD_AREA= D.ID_CODIGO AND E.AREA = S.COD_AREA) AS SUPERVISOR ,
        E.LUNES AS LUNES,
        E.MARTES AS MARTES,  
        E.MIERCOLES AS MIERCOLES,
        E.JUEVES AS JUEVES,  
        E.VIERNES AS VIERNES,
        E.SABADO AS SABADO,
        E.DOMINGO AS DOMINGO,   
        E.COD AS COD        
        FROM HIS_MOV_PROD MH INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT E.EMPL_AREA AS AREA,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_CodEmpleado FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0)  AND (MOV_FECHA='06/01/2020'))  AS LUNES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_CodEmpleado FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0)  AND (MOV_FECHA='07/01/2020')) AS MARTES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_CodEmpleado FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0)  AND (MOV_FECHA='08/01/2020')) AS MIERCOLES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_CodEmpleado FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0)  AND (MOV_FECHA='09/01/2020')) AS JUEVES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_CodEmpleado FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0)  AND (MOV_FECHA='10/01/2020')) AS VIERNES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_CodEmpleado FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0)  AND (MOV_FECHA='11/01/2020')) AS SABADO,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_CodEmpleado FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0)  AND (MOV_FECHA='12/01/2020')) AS DOMINGO,
        E.EMPL_FECH_AF AS EMPL_FEC,
        (SELECT DISTINCT E.EMPL_COD )AS COD
        FROM TBL_EMPLEADO E INNER JOIN HIS_MOV_PROD MH ON MH.Mov_CodEmpleado=E.EMPL_COD AND E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0 AND (MH.Mov_Fecha='06/01/2020' OR MH.Mov_Fecha='07/01/2020' OR MH.Mov_Fecha='08/01/2020' 
        OR MH.Mov_Fecha='09/01/2020' OR MH.Mov_Fecha='10/01/2020' OR MH.Mov_Fecha='11/01/2020' OR MH.Mov_Fecha='12/01/2020')    
        GROUP BY E.EMPL_COD,E.EMPL_FECH_AF,E.EMPL_AREA) 
        E ON MH.Mov_CodEmpleado = E.COD
        GROUP BY E.AREA,E.COD,E.LUNES,E.MARTES,E.MIERCOLES,E.JUEVES,E.VIERNES,E.SABADO,E.DOMINGO
        ORDER BY AREA
            
INSERT INTO #CUADROCOMP(AREA,SUPERVISOR,LUNES,MARTES,MIERCOLES,JUEVES,VIERNES,SABADO,DOMINGO,EMPLCOD)   
         SELECT 
          (SELECT ISNULL(CASE WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='EMPAQUE MANUAL PAGO POR DIA') THEN 'EMPAQUE            '
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA )='EMPAQUE NORMAL') THEN 'EMPAQUE'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA )='EMPAQUE MANUAL 2') THEN 'EMPAQUE'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA )='EMPAQUE MANUAL') THEN 'EMPAQUE'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA )='COCINA PAGO POR DIA') THEN 'COCINA'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA )='COCINA POR HORA') THEN 'COCINA'
                             WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA )='CAMARA PAGO POR DIA') THEN 'CAMARA'    END,
         (SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA )))AS AREA,      
        (SELECT DISTINCT(S.NOM_SUPERVISOR) FROM
  TBL_SECCION D
  INNER JOIN
  TBL_SUPERVISOR S
  ON S.COD_AREA= D.ID_CODIGO AND E.AREA = S.COD_AREA) AS SUPERVISOR ,
        E.LUNES AS LUNES,
        E.MARTES AS MARTES,  
        E.MIERCOLES AS MIERCOLES,
        E.JUEVES AS JUEVES,  
        E.VIERNES AS VIERNES,
        E.SABADO AS SABADO,
        E.DOMINGO AS DOMINGO,           
        E.COD AS COD                  
        FROM HIS_MOV_HORA MH INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT E.EMPL_AREA AS AREA,         
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_CodEmpleado FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA='06/01/2020'))  AS LUNES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_CodEmpleado FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA='07/01/2020')) AS MARTES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_CodEmpleado FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0)  AND (MOV_FECHA='08/01/2020')) AS MIERCOLES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_CodEmpleado FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0)  AND (MOV_FECHA='09/01/2020')) AS JUEVES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_CodEmpleado FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA='10/01/2020')) AS VIERNES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_CodEmpleado FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0)  AND (MOV_FECHA='11/01/2020')) AS SABADO,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_CodEmpleado FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0)  AND (MOV_FECHA='12/01/2020')) AS DOMINGO,
        E.EMPL_FECH_AF AS EMPL_FEC,
        (SELECT DISTINCT E.EMPL_COD )AS COD
        FROM TBL_EMPLEADO E INNER JOIN HIS_MOV_HORA MH ON MH.Mov_CodEmpleado=E.EMPL_COD AND E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0 AND (MH.Mov_Fecha='06/01/2020' OR MH.Mov_Fecha='07/01/2020' OR MH.Mov_Fecha='08/01/2020' 
        OR MH.Mov_Fecha='09/01/2020' OR MH.Mov_Fecha='10/01/2020' OR MH.Mov_Fecha='11/01/2020' OR MH.Mov_Fecha='12/01/2020')    
        GROUP BY E.EMPL_COD,E.EMPL_FECH_AF,E.EMPL_AREA) 
        E ON MH.Mov_CodEmpleado=E.COD
        GROUP BY E.AREA,E.EMPL_FEC,E.COD,E.LUNES,E.MARTES,E.MIERCOLES,E.JUEVES,E.VIERNES,E.SABADO,E.DOMINGO
                
    
; WITH VISTA AS (SELECT
    
    AREA,
 SUPERVISOR,
LUNES AS LUNES,
MARTES AS MARTES,
MIERCOLES AS MIERCOLES,
 JUEVES AS JUEVES,
VIERNES AS VIERNES,
SABADO AS SABADO,
DOMINGO AS DOMINGO
FROM
    #CUADROCOMP
    )
    
SELECT 
DISTINCT * FROM VISTA ORDER BY SUPERVISOR
```

De antemano agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: Los registros con código 2256 en un día de la semana son dos. Uno lo tiene en un día, el otro en dos días. ¿Cuál debe ser el criterio para eliminar duplicados? ¿Cuándo consideras que un registro es duplicado? Esto no es claro en tu pregunta y sin eso, no es posible ayudarte.

Comment: Lo ponía como ejemplo el código 2256, pero lo que necesito es que por cada día de cada una de las 7 columnas (lunes a domingo) los registros que se encuentren duplicados sean eliminados para que no se cuente doble al momento de realizar el agrupamiento posteriormente.

Comment: que es un registro duplicado? como se define un registro duplicado?

Comment: Seguimos intentando que nos expliques cómo se define un duplicado. Digamos que el domingo vamos a retirar los registros duplicados; significa que sólo debe haber un registro con cada valor (entonces, uno de los dos 2256 no se mostraría)? Y así por cada día?

Comment: Como se ve en la imagen el código 2256 realizo 2 labores ese día lunes, por lo cual solo debería quedar uno de los 2 registros, con lo cual uno entendería que asistió a laborar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de varios días tratando de obtener la solución termine dando con ella y como buen compañero adjunto el código ya implementado como procedimiento y con su respectiva captura de que realiza lo solicitado.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CuadroComparativoEventualHis]
@FECHAL VARCHAR(10),
@FECHAMA VARCHAR(10),
@FECHAMI VARCHAR(10),
@FECHAJU VARCHAR(10),
@FECHAVI VARCHAR(10),
@FECHASA VARCHAR(10),
@FECHADO VARCHAR(10)
AS
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#CUADROCOMP') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #CUADROCOMP;
END 

SET LANGUAGE SPANISH; 
CREATE TABLE #CUADROCOMP (
EMPLCOD INT,
SUPERVISOR VARCHAR(50),
AREA VARCHAR(50),
LUNES VARCHAR(50),
MARTES VARCHAR(50),
MIERCOLES VARCHAR(50),
JUEVES VARCHAR(50),
VIERNES VARCHAR(50),
SABADO VARCHAR(50),
DOMINGO VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO #CUADROCOMP(AREA,SUPERVISOR,LUNES,MARTES,MIERCOLES,JUEVES,VIERNES,SABADO,DOMINGO,EMPLCOD)
         SELECT 
          (SELECT ISNULL(CASE WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='EMPAQUE MANUAL PAGO POR DIA') THEN 'EMPAQUE            '
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='EMPAQUE NORMAL') THEN 'EMPAQUE'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='EMPAQUE MANUAL 2') THEN 'EMPAQUE'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='EMPAQUE MANUAL') THEN 'EMPAQUE'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='COCINA PAGO POR DIA') THEN 'COCINA'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='COCINA POR HORA') THEN 'COCINA'
                             WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='CAMARA PAGO POR DIA') THEN 'CAMARA' END,
         (SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)))AS AREA,       
        (SELECT DISTINCT(S.NOM_SUPERVISOR) FROM
  TBL_SECCION D
  INNER JOIN
  TBL_SUPERVISOR S
  ON S.COD_AREA= D.ID_CODIGO AND E.AREA = S.COD_AREA) AS SUPERVISOR ,
E.LUNES AS LUNES,
        E.MARTES AS MARTES,  
        E.MIERCOLES AS MIERCOLES,
        E.JUEVES AS JUEVES,  
        E.VIERNES AS VIERNES,
        E.SABADO AS SABADO,
        E.DOMINGO AS DOMINGO,       
        E.COD AS COD        
        FROM HIS_MOV_PROD MH INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT E.EMPL_AREA AS AREA,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_Fecha FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA=@FECHAL))  AS LUNES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_Fecha FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA=@FECHAMA)) AS MARTES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_Fecha FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA=@FECHAMI)) AS MIERCOLES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_Fecha FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA=@FECHAJU)) AS JUEVES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_Fecha FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA=@FECHAVI)) AS VIERNES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_Fecha FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA=@FECHASA)) AS SABADO,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_Fecha FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA=@FECHADO)) AS DOMINGO,
        E.EMPL_FECH_AF AS EMPL_FEC,
        E.EMPL_COD AS COD
        FROM TBL_EMPLEADO E INNER JOIN HIS_MOV_PROD MH ON MH.Mov_CodEmpleado=E.EMPL_COD AND E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0 AND E.EMPL_COD != 1543 AND (MH.Mov_Fecha=@FECHAL OR MH.Mov_Fecha=@FECHAMA OR MH.Mov_Fecha=@FECHAMI 
        OR MH.Mov_Fecha=@FECHAJU OR MH.Mov_Fecha=@FECHAVI OR MH.Mov_Fecha=@FECHASA OR MH.Mov_Fecha=@FECHADO)    
        GROUP BY E.EMPL_COD,E.EMPL_FECH_AF,E.EMPL_AREA) 
        E ON MH.Mov_CodEmpleado = E.COD
        GROUP BY E.AREA,E.COD,E.LUNES,E.MARTES,E.MIERCOLES,E.JUEVES,E.VIERNES,E.SABADO,E.DOMINGO
        ORDER BY AREA
            
INSERT INTO #CUADROCOMP(AREA,SUPERVISOR,LUNES,MARTES,MIERCOLES,JUEVES,VIERNES,SABADO,DOMINGO,EMPLCOD)   
         SELECT 
          (SELECT ISNULL(CASE WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA)='EMPAQUE MANUAL PAGO POR DIA') THEN 'EMPAQUE            '
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA )='EMPAQUE NORMAL') THEN 'EMPAQUE'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA )='EMPAQUE MANUAL 2') THEN 'EMPAQUE'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA )='EMPAQUE MANUAL') THEN 'EMPAQUE'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA )='COCINA PAGO POR DIA') THEN 'COCINA'
         WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA )='COCINA POR HORA') THEN 'COCINA'
                             WHEN ((SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA )='CAMARA PAGO POR DIA') THEN 'CAMARA'    END,
         (SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.AREA )))AS AREA,      
        (SELECT DISTINCT(S.NOM_SUPERVISOR) FROM
  TBL_SECCION D
  INNER JOIN
  TBL_SUPERVISOR S
  ON S.COD_AREA= D.ID_CODIGO AND E.AREA = S.COD_AREA) AS SUPERVISOR ,
E.LUNES AS LUNES,
        E.MARTES AS MARTES,  
        E.MIERCOLES AS MIERCOLES,
        E.JUEVES AS JUEVES,  
        E.VIERNES AS VIERNES,
        E.SABADO AS SABADO,
        E.DOMINGO AS DOMINGO,       
        E.COD AS COD                  
        FROM HIS_MOV_HORA MH INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT E.EMPL_AREA AS AREA,         
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_Fecha FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0)  AND (MOV_FECHA=@FECHAL))  AS LUNES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_Fecha FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA=@FECHAMA)) AS MARTES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_Fecha FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA=@FECHAMI)) AS MIERCOLES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_Fecha FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA=@FECHAJU)) AS JUEVES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_Fecha FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA=@FECHAVI)) AS VIERNES,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_Fecha FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA=@FECHASA)) AS SABADO,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Mov_Fecha FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE (MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND  E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0) AND (MOV_FECHA=@FECHADO)) AS DOMINGO,
        E.EMPL_FECH_AF AS EMPL_FEC,
        E.EMPL_COD AS COD
        FROM TBL_EMPLEADO E INNER JOIN HIS_MOV_HORA MH ON MH.Mov_CodEmpleado=E.EMPL_COD AND E.EMPL_FECH_AF=0 AND E.EMPL_COD != 1543 AND (MH.Mov_Fecha=@FECHAL OR MH.Mov_Fecha=@FECHAMA OR MH.Mov_Fecha=@FECHAMI 
        OR MH.Mov_Fecha=@FECHAJU OR MH.Mov_Fecha=@FECHAVI OR MH.Mov_Fecha=@FECHASA OR MH.Mov_Fecha=@FECHADO)    
        GROUP BY E.EMPL_COD,E.EMPL_FECH_AF,E.EMPL_AREA) 
        E ON MH.Mov_CodEmpleado=E.COD
        GROUP BY E.AREA,E.COD,E.LUNES,E.MARTES,E.MIERCOLES,E.JUEVES,E.VIERNES,E.SABADO,E.DOMINGO
                
    
;WITH VISTA AS(
 SELECT  
                
(SELECT DISTINCT AREA) AS AREA,
        (SELECT DISTINCT SUPERVISOR) AS SUPERVISOR      
 ,(SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(CASE WHEN (COUNT(LUNES) != '0') THEN '1' END ,0)) AS LUNES
 ,(SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(CASE WHEN (COUNT(MARTES) != '0') THEN '1' END ,0)) AS MARTES
 ,(SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(CASE WHEN (COUNT(MIERCOLES) != '0') THEN '1' END ,0)) AS MIERCOLES
 ,(SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(CASE WHEN (COUNT(JUEVES) != '0') THEN '1' END ,0)) AS JUEVES
 ,(SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(CASE WHEN (COUNT(VIERNES) != '0') THEN '1' END ,0)) AS VIERNES
 ,(SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(CASE WHEN (COUNT(SABADO) != '0') THEN '1' END ,0)) AS SABADO
 ,(SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(CASE WHEN (COUNT(DOMINGO) != '0') THEN '1' END ,0)) AS DOMINGO
FROM #CUADROCOMP GROUP BY EMPLCOD,AREA,SUPERVISOR)


SELECT DISTINCT AREA,
SUPERVISOR,
SUM(CONVERT(INT,(LUNES))) AS LUNES,
SUM(CONVERT (INT,(MARTES))) AS MARTES,
SUM(CONVERT (INT,(MIERCOLES))) AS MIERCOLES,
 SUM(CONVERT (INT,(JUEVES))) AS JUEVES,
SUM(CONVERT (INT,(VIERNES))) AS VIERNES,
SUM(CONVERT (INT,(SABADO))) AS SABADO,
SUM(CONVERT (INT,(DOMINGO))) AS DOMINGO
 FROM VISTA 
GROUP BY AREA,SUPERVISOR ORDER BY AREA
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]